# What is the group generated by all reflections around arbitrary lines in 3D space?

Tags: linear-transformations, linear-groups

A rigid transformation (also called Euclidean transformation or Euclidean isometry) is a geometric transformation of a Euclidean space that preserves the Euclidean distance between every pair of points.

The rigid transformations include rotations, translations, reflections, or any sequence of these.
A reflection (also spelled reflexion) is a mapping from a Euclidean space to itself that is an isometry with a hyperplane as a set of fixed points; this set is called the axis (in dimension 2) or plane (in dimension 3) of reflection.

By Cartan–Dieudonné theorem in three-dimensional Euclidean space, every orthogonal transformation can be described as a single reflection, a rotation (2 reflections), or an improper rotation (3 reflections).
The set of all (proper and improper) rigid transformations is a mathematical group called the Euclidean group, denoted $E(n)$ for n-dimensional Euclidean spaces.
Now suppose $l$ is an arbitrary line in Euclidean three-dimensional space. Suppose that the transformation $T$ is a reflection with respect to the line $l$ in three-dimensional space.
Call the group generated by all these $T$'s $G$. Can group $G$ be identified?

Comment: I think they generate the whole orthogonal group

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any comment?

Comment: If $n-k$ is odd, then the set of all reflections across $k$-dim affine subspaces of $n$-dim space generates all isometries, and the set of all reflections across $k$-dim vector subspaces of $n$-dim space generates all linear isometries. If $n-k$ is even, then the set of all reflections across $k$-dim affine subspaces of $n$-dim space generates all orientation-preserving isometries, and the set of all reflections across $k$-dim vector subspaces of $n$-dim space generates all linear orientation-preserving isometries.

Answer (score 1):

I assume any line here crosses the origin, otherwise it will not be a linear subspace

If y is the reflection of x with respect a plane H, then it is at the same time the reflection of x with respect to the line that connects the origin and the intersection of H and the line segment x-y, therefore the group generated by reflection of lines is at least as large as the group generated by reflection of planes, i.e., $E(n)$

On the other hand, it is clear that x,y haves equal length, so any such transformation must be rigid, i.e, it is no larger than $E(n)$, consequently it is $E(n)$

Remark: If P is the orthogonal projection onto a line, then the reflection with respect to this line is simply $2P-I$ where I is the identity.

Comment: Not being a linear subspace is not a problem. The Euclidean group $E(n)$ has many nonlinear isometries. OP mentioned translations, for example. | Your first paragraph shows that for any plane reflection that swaps two particular points $x$ and $y$, there exists a line reflection that also swaps $x$ and $y$. This by itself doesn't actually prove plane reflections are generated by line reflections, though. In fact that would be impossible: plane reflections reverse orientation, while line reflections do not, so no plane reflection is a composition of line reflections.

Comment: There is a bug. You checked the problem for only one point x. The plane H you found may not be suitable for the line we are looking for.

Comment: you will not get an isometry if affine planes are allowed. For example, reflect the point (0,0,1)  w.r.t. the affine plane z=1 , you will get (0,0,3), the length will be changed.

Comment: And plane reflections are line reflections if you chose the line properly, for example, reflect the point (0,0,1)  w.r.t. the xy plane  you get (0,0,-1), which is same as the reflection w.r.t. the x axis.